# How To Display Fully Visible Keys With Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey PowerShell Command?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

When i run following command:

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname"
```

I'll get the following result:
[image]

How can i get the keys showing fully visible so that i can use it as variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Format-List](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113302) cmdlet to expand the properties:

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname" | Format-List * -force
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround by debugging the command, so this was the command to show the keys completely:

```
$DebugPreference = “Continue”
write-debug (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname")
```

EDIT:

I obviously have something wrong here, `write-debug` works, but it also give an error at the end, saying:
Write-Debug : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKey

That is not an issue as long as it outputs the keys full, but I'm probably using `write-debug` command wrong way, because when i want to save the output to a file by using:

```
$DebugPreference = “Continue”
write-debug (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname") | Out-File output.txt
```

No file is created.

Can anyone help me to finish this task please? So that I'll have a complete solution to output keys into a file then locate the key string from that file and use it as variable in next command.

Here is how the output look like:
[image]
I just need to capture key1, that's the long string starting after "value": "